# Count the number of lines in a file without reading entire file into memory?

Tags: ruby

I'm processing huge data files (millions of lines each).

Before I start processing I'd like to get a count of the number of lines in the file, so I can then indicate how far along the processing is.

Because of the size of the files, it would not be practical to read the entire file into memory, just to count how many lines there are.  Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you are in a Unix environment, you can just let `wc -l` do the work.

It will not load the whole file into memory; since it is optimized for streaming file and count word/line the performance is good enough rather then streaming the file yourself in Ruby.

**SSCCE:**

```
filename = 'a_file/somewhere.txt'
line_count = `wc -l "#{filename}"`.strip.split(' ')[0].to_i
p line_count
```

Or if you want a collection of files passed on the command line:

```
wc_output = `wc -l "#{ARGV.join('" "')}"`
line_count = wc_output.match(/^ *([0-9]+) +total$/).captures[0].to_i
p line_count
```

Comment: WC is so fast that one probably won't need a progress counter.

Comment: There's an edge condition: if the last line of the file doesn't have a newline, wc comes up one short. This is by posix design, see http://backreference.org/2010/05/23/sanitizing-files-with-no-trailing-newline/

Comment: please do more than just cite the method, cite an example of wc -l in practice. not everybody knows the things which are obvious to you. (I know, "Google harder!"...but if we could all be more like Ruby, we would do this instinctively.)

Comment: Solution for the edge condition (if the last line doesn't have newline): 
`count = %x{sed -n '=' #{file} | wc -l}.to_i `
Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616039/wc-command-of-mac-showing-one-less-result

Comment: line_count = `wc -l "#{filename}" | cut -d" " -f1`.to_i

Comment: It is important to note that `filename` should be a trusted input when calling `wc -l "#{filename}"`. Otherwise I suggest using `Shellwords.escape`. The issue being for instance `filename = "file; echo pwnd"`.

Answer (score 79):

Reading the file a line at a time:

```
count = File.foreach(filename).inject(0) {|c, line| c+1}
```

or the Perl-ish

```
File.foreach(filename) {}
count = $.
```

or

```
count = 0
File.open(filename) {|f| count = f.read.count("\n")}
```

Will be slower than

```
count = %x{wc -l #{filename}}.split.first.to_i
```

Comment: The last one is the cleanest, since we can assume "wc" is optimized for good I/O speeds. The ".split.first" are superfluous, and don't forget to add single quotes around the filename, or it will fail on filenames that have spaces. Simplified: %x{wc -l '#{filename}'}.to_i

Comment: or `count = %x{wc -l < "#{filename}"}.to_i`

Comment: @deafgreatdane I don't think `wc` is "clean". Now it won't run on Windows .. I would take a small performance hit (within the same complexity class) to avoid portability issues.

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't matter what language you're using, you're going to have to read the whole file if the lines are of variable length. That's because the newlines could be anywhere and theres no way to know without reading the file (assuming it isn't cached, which generally speaking it isn't).

If you want to indicate progress, you have two realistic options. You can extrapolate progress based on assumed line length:

```
assumed lines in file = size of file / assumed line size
progress = lines processed / assumed lines in file * 100%
```

since you know the size of the file. Alternatively you can measure progress as:

```
progress = bytes processed / size of file * 100%
```

This should be sufficient.

Comment: actually for my needs this is probably a better idea that counting the number of lines.

Comment: I'm assuming the original poster was ok with reading through the file, just not having the entire contents of it in memory.

Answer (score 12):

using ruby:

```
file=File.open("path-to-file","r")
file.readlines.size
```

39 milliseconds faster then wc -l on a 325.477 lines file

Comment: Your system's `wc` has issues.

Comment: I am quite sure you cannot do this with a huge file because its content will be entirely held in memory.

Comment: Using `readlines` or `read` is not scalable. It's also slower than reading line-by-line using `foreach` once the files get beyond 1MB in size. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25189262/128421

Answer (score 12):

**Summary of the posted solutions**

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'csv'

filename = "name.csv"

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { `wc -l < #{filename}`.to_i }
  x.report { File.open(filename).inject(0) { |c, line| c + 1 } }
  x.report { File.foreach(filename).inject(0) {|c, line| c+1} }
  x.report { File.read(filename).scan(/\n/).count }
  x.report { CSV.open(filename, "r").readlines.count }
end
```

File with 807802 lines:

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.000000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.030606)
   0.370000   0.050000   0.420000 (  0.412472)
   0.360000   0.010000   0.370000 (  0.374642)
   0.290000   0.020000   0.310000 (  0.315488)
   3.190000   0.060000   3.250000 (  3.245171)
```

Comment: [I've rewritten a bit your benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60434970/6320039), if you'd rather like I to edit your answer, just ping me here :)

Answer (score 8):

**DISCLAIMER:** the already existing benchmark used `count` rather than `length` or `size` (which is notoriously slower in ruby). And
was tedious to read IMHO. Hence this new answer.

## Benchmark

```rb
require "benchmark"
require "benchmark/ips"
require "csv"

filename = ENV.fetch("FILENAME")

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("wc") { `wc -l #{filename}`.to_i }
  x.report("open") { File.open(filename).inject(0, :next) }
  x.report("foreach") { File.foreach(filename).inject(0, :next) }
  x.report("foreach $.") { File.foreach(filename) {}; $. }
  x.report("read.scan.length") { File.read(filename).scan(/\n/).length }
  x.report("CSV.open.readlines") { CSV.open(filename, "r").readlines.length }
  x.report("IO.readlines.length") { IO.readlines(filename).length }

  x.compare!
end
```

On my MacBook Pro (2017) with a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 processor:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
                  wc     8.000  i/100ms
                open     2.000  i/100ms
             foreach     2.000  i/100ms
          foreach $.     2.000  i/100ms
    read.scan.length     2.000  i/100ms
  CSV.open.readlines     1.000  i/100ms
 IO.readlines.length     2.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
                  wc    115.014  (±21.7%) i/s -    552.000  in   5.020531s
                open     22.450  (±26.7%) i/s -    104.000  in   5.049692s
             foreach     32.669  (±27.5%) i/s -    150.000  in   5.046793s
          foreach $.     25.244  (±31.7%) i/s -    112.000  in   5.020499s
    read.scan.length     44.102  (±31.7%) i/s -    190.000  in   5.033218s
  CSV.open.readlines      2.395  (±41.8%) i/s -     12.000  in   5.262561s
 IO.readlines.length     36.567  (±27.3%) i/s -    162.000  in   5.089395s

Comparison:
                  wc:      115.0 i/s
    read.scan.length:       44.1 i/s - 2.61x  slower
 IO.readlines.length:       36.6 i/s - 3.15x  slower
             foreach:       32.7 i/s - 3.52x  slower
          foreach $.:       25.2 i/s - 4.56x  slower
                open:       22.4 i/s - 5.12x  slower
  CSV.open.readlines:        2.4 i/s - 48.02x  slower
```

This was made with a file containing 75 516 lines, and 3 532 510 characters (~47 chars per line). You should try this with your own file/dimensions and computer for a precise result.

Answer (score 3):

Same as DJ's answer, but giving the actual Ruby code:

```
count = %x{wc -l file_path}.split[0].to_i
```

The first part

```
wc -l file_path
```

Gives you

```
num_lines file_path
```

The `split` and `to_i` put that into a number.

Answer (score 2):

For reasons I don't fully understand, scanning the file for newlines using `File` seems to be a lot faster than doing `CSV#readlines.count`.

The following benchmark used a CSV file with 1,045,574 lines of a data and 4 columns:

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.639000   0.047000   0.686000 (  0.682000)
  17.067000   0.171000  17.238000 ( 17.221173)
```

The code for the benchmark is below:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'csv'

file = "1-25-2013 DATA.csv"

Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report { File.read(file).scan(/\n/).count }
    x.report { CSV.open(file, "r").readlines.count }
end
```

As you can see, scanning the file for newlines is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: The scan forces in-memory and the file object is leaked.

Comment: For a 10M lines file I see IOError: File too large.

Comment: `File.read` loads it and does nothing to it. `CSV.open(...).readlines` reads and parses every line into arrays. You're comparing apples to oranges so, of course, there is going to be a big difference in speed.

Comment: Not to mention a CSV entry could have newlines in a field without actually being a new csv row itself -- the `File.read` will not recognize this.

Answer (score 2):

I have this one liner.

```
puts File.foreach('myfile.txt').count
```

Comment: This is OK only if you're OK with loading the whole file into system memory. Using `wc` scales better to large files.

Answer (score 2):

The test results for more than 135k lines are shown below.
This is my benchmark code.

```
 file_name = '100m.csv'
 Benchmark.bm do |x|
   x.report { File.new(file_name).readlines.size }
   x.report { `wc -l "#{file_name}"`.strip.split(' ')[0].to_i }
   x.report { File.read(file_name).scan(/\n/).count }
 end
```

result is

```
   user     system      total        real
 0.100000   0.040000   0.140000 (  0.143636)
 0.000000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.093293)
 0.380000   0.060000   0.440000 (  0.464925)
```

The `wc -l` code has one problem.
If there is only one line in the file and the last character does not end with `\n`, then count is zero.

So, I recommend calling wc when you count more then one line.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a CSV file, the length of the records should be pretty uniform if the content of the file is numeric.   Wouldn't it make sense to just divide the size of the file by the length of the record or a mean of the first 100 records.

Comment: This *should* return a value that's somewhere in the ballpark.

Answer (score 1):

Using `foreach` without `inject` is about 3% faster than with `inject`.  Both are very much faster (more than 100x in my experience) than using `getc`.

Using `foreach` without `inject` can also be slightly simplified (relative to the snippet given elsewhere in this thread) as follows:

```
count = 0;  File.foreach(path) { count+=1}
puts "count: #{count}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With UNIX style text files, it's very simple

```
f = File.new("/path/to/whatever")
num_newlines = 0
while (c = f.getc) != nil
  num_newlines += 1 if c == "\n"
end
```

That's it.  For MS Windows text files, you'll have to check for
a sequence of "\r\n" instead of just "\n", but that's not much
more difficult.  For Mac OS Classic text files (as opposed to
Mac OS X), you would check for "\r" instead of "\n".

So, yeah, this looks like C.  So what?  C's awesome and Ruby is
awesome because when a C answer is easiest that's what you can
expect your Ruby code to look like.  Hopefully your dain hasn't
already been bramaged by Java.

By the way, please don't even consider any of the answers above
that use the `IO#read` or `IO#readlines` method in turn calling a
String method on what's been read.  You said you didn't want to
read the whole file into memory and that's exactly what these do.
This is why Donald Knuth recommends people understand how to program
closer to the hardware because if they don't they'll end up writing
"weird code".  Obviously you don't want to code close to the
hardware whenever you don't have to, but that should be common sense.
However you should learn to recognize the instances which you do have
to get closer to the nuts and bolts such as this one.

And don't try to get more "object oriented" than the situation
calls for.  That's an embarrassing trap for newbies who want to look
more sophisticated than they really are.  You should always be glad
for the times when the answer really is simple, and not be
disappointed when there's no complexity to give you the opportunity
to write "impressive" code.  However if you want to look somewhat
"object oriented" and don't mind reading an entire line into
memory at a time (i.e., you know the lines are short enough), you
can do this

```
f = File.new("/path/to/whatever")
num_newlines = 0
f.each_line do
  num_newlines += 1
end
```

This would be a good compromise but only if the lines aren't too
long in which case it might even run more quickly than my first
solution.

Comment: While this has some good information, such as "don't try to get more "object oriented" than the situation calls for", the code isn't best-practice: You're failing to close your file handle. Either do it explicitly, or use a block with `File.open` and let Ruby do it for you. However, using `File.foreach` with a counter inside would be even simpler and just as fast.

Answer (score 0):

`wc -l` in Ruby with less memory, the lazy way:

```ruby
(ARGV.length == 0 ?
 [["", STDIN]] :
    ARGV.lazy.map { |file_name|
        [file_name, File.open(file_name)]
})
.map { |file_name, file|
    "%8d %s\n" % [*file
                    .each_line
                    .lazy
                    .map { |line| 1 }
                    .reduce(:+), file_name]
}
.each(&:display)
```

as originally shown by [Shugo Maeda](http://shugomaeda.blogspot.it/2012/03/enumerablelazy-and-its-benefits.html).

Example:

```
$ curl -s -o wc.rb -L https://git.io/vVrQi
$ chmod u+x wc.rb
$ ./wc.rb huge_data_file.csv
  43217291 huge_data_file.csv
```

Answer (score -2):

You can read the last line only and see its number:

```
f = File.new('huge-file')
f.readlines[-1]
count = f.lineno
```