# Get line count before looping over data in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to get the total number of lines that an IO object contains before looping through each line in the IO object. How can I do this in ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of lines in a file with Ruby, without reading entire file into memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650517/count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file-with-ruby-without-reading-entire-file-into-m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really, unless you want to shell out to `wc` and parse the result of that - otherwise you'll need to do two passes - one to get the line numbers, and another to do your actual work.

(assuming we're talking about a `File` `IO` instance - neither of those approaches work for network sockets etc)

Comment: He never said anything about not being a File IO instance. It all depends on whether your IO is a stream or a non-stream. If it's a non-stream, you can definitely count the lines.

Answer (score 1):

in rails (the only difference is how I generate the file object instance)

```
file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'assets', 'file.json'))
linecount = file.readlines.size
```

Answer (score 0):

`io.lines.count` would give you the number of lines.

`io.lines.each_with_index {|line, index|}` would give you each line and which line number it is (starting at 0).

But I don't know if it's possible to count the number of lines without reading a file.

You may want to read a file, and then use `io.rewind` to read it again.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not humongous, slurp it into memory(array) and count the the number of items( ie lines).

Comment: No need to slurp, ruby provides a method which snaps more than it slurps, IO#readlines