# WC command of mac showing one less result

Tags: unix

I have a text file  which has over 60MB size. It has got entries in 5105043 lines, but when I am doing wc -l it is giving only 5105042 results which is one less than actual. Does anyone have any idea why it is happening?

Is it a common thing when the file size is large?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Last line does not contain a new line.

One trick to get the result you want would be:

```
sed -n '=' <yourfile> | wc -l
```

This tells `sed` just to print the line number of each line in your file which `wc` then counts. There are probably better solutions, but this works.

Comment: Yes this one is giving the right result, However wc -l continues to give the incorrect one..  I am really confued

Comment: @Batman: If you are simply trying to perform tricks, a better way to emulate the `sed` command above would be to use `awk`: `awk 'END { print NR }' file.txt`. Alternatively, if you'd like to _correct_ your file so that it has an equal number of lines and newline characters, see my edit below. HTH.

Comment: wc fails cos the last line is missing a newline. This is "cheating" - sed is outputting lines with newlines, and you are counting the sed output rather than the actual lines in your file. As noted, there are other solutions that work directly on the file. If you can append a newline that is probably the best solution, but depending on the systems involved, may not be an option.

Comment: @steve I am not playing tricks, The only reason that I put up this post was that I wanted to know to reason behind it. I have already solved which this problem is related to . I

Comment: Why not `sed -n '$='`? This command prints the number of the last line directly.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong - cos I didn't know about it! You learn something new every day !

Answer (score 4):

The last line in your file is probably missing a newline ending. IIRC, `wc -l` merely counts the number of newline characters in the file.

If you try: `cat -A file.txt | tail` does your last line contain a trailing dollar sign (`$`)?

**EDIT:**

Assuming the last line in your file is lacking a newline character, you can append a newline character to correct it like this:

```
printf "\n" >> file.txt
```

The results of `wc -l` should now be consistent.

Comment: I am getting an error running this command..cat: illegal option -- A

Comment: I'm not familiar with all of the versions of `cat`. I'm using `cat (GNU coreutils) 8.17`. Does yours have a `--show-all` option? If not, you could try `cat -vET file.txt | tail`, which should have the same result, and this may apply to more flavors of `cat`.

Comment: I just ran into this where I know that my list is one per line (took a one line space separated csv file and sed to get one per line). I thought there might be duplicates so I ran through sort -u but was surprised that the sorted list was one more than the WORD count in wc... In other words, wc on the original file showed one less word than line 1073 vs 1074. This seemed wrong to me. When I look at the file in Sublime Text I see 1074 lines (the last line number is 1074 and has a value in it). I still haven't figured out what/where the discrepancy is.

Comment: @user107172: Does the file contain Windows carriage returns? Make a copy of your file, then `dos2unix yourfile.csv`.

Comment: The issue was the lack of a trailing newline on the last line of the file. In that case the last line is not counted as a line, but the words/bytes in it are counted.

Answer (score 0):

60 MB seems a bit big file but for small size files. One option could be

```
cat -n file.txt
```

OR

```
cat -n sample.txt | cut -f1 | tail -1
```