# Using the line count command wc -l <document_name> (Linux), I am getting a return of the number of lines minus 1

Tags: linux, wc

It looks like the number of carriage returns is what is being counted.
Also, the command line is concatenated with the last line of text when I do the cat command.
So,

*cat newdoc*

gives me the last line

*be savedorangepi@OrangePi:~*

where '*be saved*' is the last line of the document with the cmd line continuing on the same line
and

*wc -l newdoc*

returns

*9 newdoc*

*orangepi@OrangePi:~*

for a 10 line document **without** the cmd line continuing on the same line.

Comment: *It looks like the number of carriage returns is what is being counted*.  That would be exactly as expected if you read the [wc manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc): "-l
print the newline counts". Anyway, this is not a programming question and is thus off-topic for Stack Overwflow.

Comment: Your file probably doesn't have a newline at the end like normal text files are expected to have.

Comment: This question has answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616039/wc-command-of-mac-showing-one-less-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with `wc` as it will NOT count the very last line unless it has the EOL character at the end. Use `grep -c "" filename` instead.