# How do I find the percent complete when parsing a file?

Tags: ruby

How can I print what percentage of a file I have already parsed. I am parsing a text file, so I use:

```
file.each_line do
```

Is there a method like `each_with_index` that is available to use with strings?

This is how I currently use `each_with_index` to find percentage complete:

```
amount = 10000000
file.each_with_index do |line, index|
      if index == amount
        break
      end
      print "%.1f%% done" % (index/(amount * 1.0) * 100)
      print "\r"
```

Comment: If you are treating the file as a stream (`each_line`), how can it be known in advance how many lines there are?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of lines in a file with Ruby, without reading entire file into memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650517/count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file-with-ruby-without-reading-entire-file-into)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all the lines upfront, then display the progress as you perform whatever operation you need on them.

```
lines = file.readlines
amount = lines.length

lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
  if index == amount
    break
  end
  print "%.1f%% done" % (index/(amount * 1.0) * 100)
  print "\r"
end
```

Comment: Exactly. That is the answer implicit in my comment above.

Comment: Working although memory inefficient solution as whole file is kept in memory. I'd suggest to guess amount by average/median of 1st rows divided by `File::size`, optionally adjust if deviation exceeds bounds.

Comment: This isn't a scalable solution. I get files that are much larger than the available RAM on a well-stocked host and this would take the host to its knees.

Answer (score 4):

To get the number of lines, you can do a couple different things.

If you are on Linux or Mac OS, take advantage of the underlying OS and ask it how many lines are in the file:

```
lines_in_file = `wc -l #{ path_to_file_to_read }`
```

`wc` is extremely fast, and can tell you about lines, words and characters. `-l` specifies lines.

If you want to do it in Ruby, you *could* use `File.readlines('/path/to/file/to/read')` or `File.read('/path/to/file/to/read').lines`, but be very careful. Both will read the entire file into memory, and, if that file is bigger than your available RAM you've just beaten your machine to a slow death. So, don't do that.

Instead use something like:

```
lines_in_file = 0
File.foreach('/path/to/file/to/read') { lines_in_file += 1 }
```

After running, `lines_in_file` will hold the number of lines in the file. `File.foreach` is VERY fast, pretty much equal to using `File.readlines` and probably faster than `File.read().lines`, and it only reads a line at a time so you're not filling your RAM.

If you want to know the current line number of the line you just read from a file, you can use Ruby's `$.`.

You're concerned about "percentage of a file" though. A potential problem with this is lines are variable length. Depending on what you are doing with them, the line length could have a big effect on your progress meter. You might want to look at the actual length of the file and keep track of the number of characters consumed by reading each line, so your progress is based on percentage of characters, rather than percentage of lines.

Comment: A File instance has a `lineno` method (more readable than `$.`)

Comment: @steenslag, good point. I keep forgetting `lineno`, probably because my years of writing in Perl corrupted my memory banks.

Comment: @theTinMan What's wrong with Perl!? :]  Although I agree, it rears it's head far too often when I write code in other languages.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Nothing. It's a great language and I wrote in it from v2 forward, but I grew tired of line noise.

Answer (score 1):

Without having to load the file beforehand, you could employ `size` and `pos` methods:

```
f = open('myfile')
while (line = f.gets)
  puts "#{(f.pos*100)/f.size}%\t#{line}"
end
```

Less lines, less logic and accurate to a byte.

Comment: +1 But it's a good habit to close the file (`f.close`) when it is opened like this. Also for better performance store the filesize in a variable before the loop.

Comment: Use the block form with `IO` and `File` methods to auto-close them.

Comment: @steenslag I realised about the `close` as I was posting this, however I didn't deem it necessary for purposes of demonstration of the core principle (similarly to the dummy code inside the `while`). Thanks for the note however!

Comment: On the storing of the file size in a variable - this was in my first version of the snippet. Then I thought to get rid of it for shortness' sake, with additional side-effect of being able to track a growing file ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the whole file and loading it in memory (as with `read` or `readlines`), I suggest to use `File.foreach` reading the file as a stream, line by line.

```
count = 0
File.foreach('your_file') { count += 1 }
idx = 0
File.foreach('your_file') do |line|
  puts "#{(idx+1).to_f / count * 100}%"
  idx += 1
end
```

Comment: Doesn't this read the file 2 times, which takes 2 times a long. This could be a problem. If you need to display a "x% done" for reading a file, it might be pretty time consuming, even without reading it 2 times.

Comment: @PhilippTessenow totally agree, but you cannot do otherwise IMO, you need to read the files to count the lines. You cannot deduce it from its size (Except if you know what each line takes). That's why I'd use `wc` (cf my update)

Comment: What about reading the file's content as a an array of strings, count the lines by checking the size of the array and then parse the strings of the array?

Comment: Exactly so, @N.N. That is the whole point of my comment above: if you need to know how many lines there are, the file is no longer a stream; it's just a big string, so you might as well just do a read_lines and have done with it. Now you've got an array and can proceed normally.

Comment: @matt right, but for big files, it won't be possible as you need to put it in memory

Comment: "but for big files, it won't be possible as you need to put it in memory", then `file.read` will fail as will `file.lines` because both need to pull it into memory.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks to you I've read about it, I had bad assumptions (due to the rewind, I though it was a true stream read). I've updated my answer. I've learned something :).

Comment: @toch But that is exactly my point. You cannot first have your entire cake and then propose to eat it only a bite it at a time. If you are truly going to treat the file as a stream, because it is big, then to speak of a "percentage" is a contradiction in terms: the stream flows until it ends, and that's all you know.

Comment: @matt ok, I understand your point. You're right. It's indeed a non sense. Considering the stream approach, the best we can would be an approximated progression based on estimation of the average bytes a line, updated at each line.